# Showing progressbar and loading image on splash in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am in need to show a splash screen having two running components one is loading image and another is progressbar.

Progressbar can be shown easily and also loading image but I don't want to use **.gif** image.

How to we achieve this?

Here is the snap short.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a custom Progress the you can use a image and rotate it using `<animated-rotate>`

Create and xml inside drawable folder,

**custom_progrress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progres_image"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Then add it to your ProgressBar in your layout,

```
 <ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/video_progress_bar"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progrress_bar" />
```

Comment: Hi Lalit I have updated my question with snap short please review it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, 
Here **loading** imageview is an GIF image which you have shown above.
**loadingText** is a TextView "Loading.." as shown above in your question.

Just manage the progress mark of the **ProgressBar** in thread accordingly, as I mentioned in the last line of my code..

```
       ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
       ProgressBar loadingProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress);
       TextView loadingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingText);

          /***
         * Starting Animation Progress bar
         */
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.looprotate);
        anim.setRepeatCount(-1);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        loading.startAnimation(anim);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingProgress.setProgress(10);
        loadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingText.setText("Connecting");
            loadingProgress.setProgress(10);

to 

        loadingProgress.setProgress(100);
```

Create An **anim.xml** in Anim folder in res:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

</rotate>
```